# How to properly use the deps folder in an Erlang project?

Tags: erlang

I am coming from the assumption that the **deps** folder of an erlang project should include **symbolic links** that point to other projects and applications, so all modules from that project can be accessed/visible.

For example, My project named **project_final** should access modules from **project_a** and **application_b**. The directory structure of them is as follows:

NOTICE: because I am using GIT, the projects have a double structure, so they are not direct siblings to each other, but instead they are placed under /projects/project_X/projectX/etc... I believe this is a problem. Any better suggestions how to manage this ?

/projects/project_a/project_a : contains ( ebin, include, src )
/projects/application_b/application_b : contains ( ebin, include, src )

/project/pro_final:

- **deps** : has **symbolic links** that point to project_a and application_b
- ebin
- include
- src : contain modules that use project_a and applicabion_b module's functions, **but gives exception error: undefined function**.

How I am executing the **project_final** test module is by:

```
cd /projects
erl -env ERL_LIBS "."
myprojectfinalmodule:test().
** exception error: undefined function project_a:test/0
```

The project_a:test module is exported and correct.

Comment: RichardC's recommendation to not use deps ( use a lib dir instead ) if I am not using rebar is to be followed. Although in the issue above, to be resolved, I was able to run properly using an additional common path to ERL_LIB such as ERL_LIBS ".:./myprojectname/deps" where deps ( or 'lib' whatever you wanna call it ) is a common parent to all related applications and projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deps directory is a Rebar convention, and should probably not be managed in any other way except through Rebar. If you're not using Rebar, don't put dependencies in a subdirectory of the application, put your individual applications under a common lib/ directory instead and use the ERL_LIBS environment variable (see http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html) to tell Erlang where to look for applications.